# Can I set a variable if any branch of my case statement is called?

Tags: ruby, variables, conditional-statements, case

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have a case statement

```
        case var1
        when cond1
          # do stuff
        when cond2
          # do stuff
        ...
        end
```

I would like to set a variable, "condition_called = true" if any of the "when" statements were invoked and leave that variable false otherwise.  Is there any way to do that other than adding

```
condition_called = true
```

within each branch of my case statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution might be to do

```
condition_called = true
case var1
when cond1
  # do stuff
when cond2
  # do stuff
else
  condition_called = false
end
```

Obviously now you can't tell if the else statement fired, but it will tell you if the `when` statements did.

More info about the Ruby `case`: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Ruby_case_Statement

Answer (score 3):

One thing to remember about Ruby `case` statements is the return values. If you can guarantee that each of your clauses returns something *truthful*, that is not `nil` or `false`, then you can depend on that behaviour:

```
condition_called =
  case ...
  when ...
    f(a)
  when ...
    g(b)
  end
```

So long as you have a result from those various operations this is pretty seamless.